# Don't break item (without disappearing footnotes)

Tags: macros, footnotes, enumerate, itemize, enumitem

I am trying to keep items (used within a command) from breaking internally, but the solutions I've found end up causing the footnotes to disappear. Any advice on how to keep the footnotes alive but still avoid breaking?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\lymessage}[3]{
  \item{{#1}\par{#2}\par{#3}\par{#3}\par{#3}\par{#3}\par{#3}\par{#3}\par{#3}
  \par{#3}\par{#3}\par{#3}\par{#3}\par{#3}}
}

\begin{enumerate}
\lymessage
  {First arg of item.\par}
  {Second arg\footnote{footnote text} of item.}
  {Another arg of item.}
\lymessage
  {First arg of item.\par}
  {Second arg\footnote{footnote text} of item.}
  {Another arg of item.}
\lymessage
  {First arg of item.\par}
  {Second arg\footnote{footnote text} of item.}
  {Another arg of item.}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help!

**Edit:** Thanks to @wipet for their solution. `\par\nobreak` in place of just `\par` works perfectly.

Comment: Your example does not make footnotes 'disappear' as far as I can tell. I'm also not sure what you mean about not having 'items' 'breaking internally': as far as I understand the meaning of the words, nothing is breaking internally. What is (not) breaking? Which foonotes are disappearing?

Comment: Item 3 breaks after the fourth line. I'm trying to avoid that. I would like for all arguments belonging to a single item to be on the same page.

Comment: You can `\def\nbpar{\par\nobreak}` and replace all `\par`s by `\nbpar` in your macro.

Comment: Ah, well, if I understand you, then what's wrong with wipet's solution?  (And if it's good, let him know so he can write an answer.)

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314375/why-does-parbox-lose-footnotes

Comment: Thanks John Kormylo - came across that thread previously as well. @wipet - that fixed the issue just fine, thanks! Apologies for the delay. I made a response to your solution already, but somehow it got lost.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea, but it's not easy to understand what you're after.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\lymessage}[3]{%
  \item \begingroup
     \let\par\fpar % don't really do \par
     \linepenalty=10000 % no page break inside a paragraph
     % the text
     #1\par
     #2\par
     #3\par #3\par #3\par #3\par #3\par #3\par
     #3\par #3\par #3\par #3\par #3\par #3%
  \endgroup\par % issue a real \par
}
\newcommand{\fpar}{% emulate \par, but just do \hfil\break
  \ifhmode
    \unskip % remove a possible space
    \vadjust{\nobreak\vskip\parskip}% insert \parskip glue
    \nobreak % don't break at the next glue
    \hskip\parfillskip % fill the line
    \break % break here
  \fi
}

\begin{enumerate}
\lymessage
  {First arg of item.}
  {Second arg\footnote{footnote text} of item.}
  {Another arg of item.}
\lymessage
  {First arg of item.}
  {Second arg\footnote{footnote text} of item.}
  {Another arg of item.}
\lymessage
  {First arg of item.}
  {Second arg\footnote{footnote text} of item.}
  {Another arg of item.}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```