# Why does \parbox lose footnotes?

Tags: footnotes, boxes

The motivation is presumably that footnotes are formatted immediately and inside a parbox `\hsize` does not equal `\textwidth` (although, unlike a minipage, `\textwidth` doesn't change).  The mechanism is presumably simply using local rather than global definitions.  Looking through `source2e` I couldn't find the source for `\@makefntext`.  I was hoping to be able to fix the problem directly.

Anyway, here is a sort of MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\savefnused
\newcount\savefndone

\newcommand{\savefootnote}[2][\empty]% #1=number (optional), #2=text
{\ifx\empty#1\footnotemark\else\footnotemark[#1]\fi
 \global\advance\savefnused by 1
 \expandafter\xdef\csname savefnmark\the\savefnused\endcsname{\thefootnote}%
 \expandafter\xdef\csname savefntext\the\savefnused\endcsname{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\flushfootnote}{\loop\ifnum\savefndone<\savefnused
  \global\advance\savefndone by 1
  \footnotetext[\csname savefnmark\the\savefndone\endcsname]%
    {\csname savefntext\the\savefndone\endcsname}%
  \global\expandafter\let\csname savefnmark\the\savefndone\endcsname\relax
  \global\expandafter\let\csname savefntext\the\savefndone\endcsname\relax
\repeat}

\begin{document}
normal\footnote{normal}

\parbox{1in}{parbox\savefootnote{parbox}}
\flushfootnote

check counter\footnote{after}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You'll fine `\@makefntext` in the respective class files. See [`article.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co), [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co) and [`report.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls?view=co), for example.

Comment: To me the answer here is that `minipage` was *designed* to handle `\footnote`s and it makes specific preparation during `\begin{minipage}` and releasing any footnotes as part of an "insert" during `\end{minipage}`. `\parbox` doesn't do this.

Comment: I know that someone with a lot more knowledge than myself will step in here to fully explain this.  From what I can tell `\parbox` has a rather complex underlying macro `\@iiiparbox`, which as part of its definition puts the textual materials in a `\vtop` box.  Since footnotes cannot be read from a `\vtop` box they cannot be used within `\parbox`. So I would think the problem is in using `\parbox`.

Comment: @AFeldman - I don't think that's it.  I often use \setbox inside a \parbox.

Comment: You probably know better then.  All I did was use `latexdef` to take a look at the definition of `\parbox` then to take a look at `\@iiiparbox` which seemed to involve `\vtop` boxes, which I know will not allow for footnotes.

Comment: The `latexdef` of `\@makefntext` is `\@makefntext:
\long macro:#1->\parindent 1em\noindent \hb@xt@ 1.8em{\hss \@makefnmark }#1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding now is that `\insert\footins{...}` will cause anything written inside the group to wind up in `\box\footins` but only AFTER the page is output.  Also, `\global\insert` is not allowed.

The macro `\global@insert` doesn't precisely mimic the `\insert` "migration" in that the contents show up immediately, but it seems to work good enough for footnotes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\global@insert}[2]% #1=box number, #2=vertical list
{\bgroup
  \setbox\@tempboxa=\box#1
  \global\setbox#1=\vbox{\unvbox\@tempboxa #2}
\egroup}

\long\def\@footnotetext#1{\global@insert\footins{%
 \reset@font\footnotesize
 \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
 \splittopskip\footnotesep
 \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
 \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
 \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
 \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark
 }%
 \color@begingroup
 \@makefntext{%
 \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
 \color@endgroup}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
normal\footnote{normal}

\begin{enumerate}
\item\parbox{1in}{parbox\footnote{parbox - \blindtext}}
\item test
\end{enumerate}

check counter\footnote{after}

\end{document}
```

---

This approach uses normal footnotes outside the `\parbox`, but requires a bit more work.  Basically it works like `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` except that you don't have to keep track of which mark goes with which text.

Inside the `\parbox` you need to add `\globalfootnotestrue` to switch modes.  After the parbox you need to add `\copyinserts` to move the footnotes from `\parboxins` to `\footins`.  Since `\parbox` is unbreakable, you don't have to worry about winding up on the wrong page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\parboxins}
\newif\ifglobalfootnotes

\newcommand{\copyinserts}{\insert\footins{\unvbox\parboxins}%
  \globalfootnotesfalse}% should be redundant

\newcommand{\global@insert}[2]% #1=box number, #2=vertical list
{\bgroup
  \setbox\@tempboxa=\box#1
  \global\setbox#1=\vbox{\unvbox\@tempboxa #2}
\egroup}

\long\def\@footnotetext#1{%
 \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
 \ifglobalfootnotes \global@insert\parboxins{\@@footnotetext{#1}}%
 \else \insert\footins{\@@footnotetext{#1}}%
 \fi}

\long\def\@@footnotetext#1{%
 \color@begingroup
 \reset@font\footnotesize
 \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
 \splittopskip\footnotesep
 \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
 \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
 \@makefntext{\rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
 \color@endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
normal\footnote{normal}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\globalfootnotestrue
  parbox\footnote{parbox - \blindtext}}%
\copyinserts
\item test
\end{enumerate}

check counter\footnote{after}

\end{document}
```