# How to know the height of the footnotes?

Tags: footnotes, boxes, height, output-routine

I tried to use the following code to get the height of the footnote box :

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Example\footnote{A footnote}. Height : \the\ht\footins.
\end{document}
```

However, I get `0.0pt`. Why and how I can fix this ?

Comment: The height of the footnote box is only known in the output routine.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why the box couldn't be generated before, Where is the footnote's content stored before ?

Comment: I checked the TeXbook because I'm not so familiar with inserts myself, but it remains really vague about this: “For example, material inserted with `\insert100` will eventually appear in `\box100`.” (page 122) Unfortunately, it doesn't say when *eventually* will be.

Comment: I ran across this problem and wound up rewrtiting footnote to use savebox commands.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314375/why-does-parbox-lose-footnotes?r=SearchResults&s=1|46.2786