# How can unite the footnote enumeration in the main text and tcolorbox?

Tags: footnotes, tcolorbox

I want a uniform footnote enumeration in the following code. For example, if the whole text has 4 footnote, 2 in the main text and 2 in the box generated by `tcolorbox,` I want all footnotes appear in the bottom of the "main page" (not in the box), and the enumeration starts from 1 and ended to 4 (no a, b, c, etc.). Also, for some reasons that is not clear to me, the picture in the box either is not generated or appears in the main text.

I should mention that I don't insist to use `tcolorbox`. If I know another method to draw those boxes generated by tcolorbox, it is fine. Since I don't see any link for attachment, I put the figure here
[image]

```
‎\documentclass{article}‎
‎\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}‎
‎\usepackage{MnSymbol}‎
‎\usepackage{wasysym}‎
‎\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}‎




‎\newtcolorbox{topbot}[1][]{empty‎, ‎notitle‎, ‎sharp corners‎, ‎borderline north= 
{0pt}{0pt}{black}‎, borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{black}‎,#1}‎

‎\begin{document}‎

A transistor is a semiconductor device used to amplify or switch 
electronicsignals and electrical power. It is composed of semiconductor 
material usually with at least three terminals for connection to an external 
circuit. A voltage or current applied to one pair of the transistor's 
terminals controls the current through another pair of terminals. Because 
the controlled (output) power can be higher than the controlling (input) 
power, a transistor can amplify a signal. Today, some transistors are 
packaged individually, but many more are found embedded in integrated 
circuits.‎‎‎‎‎‎\footnote{Footnote 1 of main text}

‎\begin{figure}‎ 
\centering‎
\includegraphics{pic.jpg}‎
\caption{Figure of main text}
\end{figure}‎


Most transistors are made from very pure silicon or germanium, but certain 
other semiconductor materials can also be used. A transistor may have only 
one kind of charge carrier, in a field effect transistor, or may have two 
kinds of charge carriers in bipolar junction transistor devices. Compared 
with the vacuum tube, transistors are generally smaller, and require less 
power to operate. Certain vacuum tubes have advantages over transistors at 
very high operating frequencies or high operating voltages. Many types of 
transistors are made to standardized specifications by multiple 
manufacturers.

‎\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable‎, ‎enhanced‎, ‎arc=0mm‎, ‎boxrule=0mm]‎‎

From November 17, 1947, to December 23, 1947, John Bardeen and Walter 
Brattain at AT&T's Bell Labs in Murray Hill, New Jersey, performed 
experiments and observed that when two gold point contacts were applied to a 
crystal of germanium, a signal was produced with the output power greater 
than the input. Solid State Physics Group leader William Shockley saw the 
potential in this, and over the next few months worked to greatly expand the 
knowledge of semiconductors.‎\footnote{Footnote of the first box}‎ 

\begin{figure}‎
\includegraphics{pic.jpg}‎
‎\caption{‎Figure that should be inside the box}
\end{figure}‎

In 1948, the point-contact transistor was independently invented by German 
physicists Herbert Mataré and Heinrich Welker while working at the Compagnie 
des Freins et Signaux, a Westinghouse subsidiary located in Paris. Mataré 
had previous experience in developing crystal rectifiers from silicon and 
germanium in the German radar effort during World War II. 
‎\end{tcolorbox}‎


‎\begin{topbot}‎

Using this knowledge, he began researching the phenomenon of "interference" 
in 1947. By June 1948, witnessing currents flowing through point-contacts, 
Mataré produced consistent results using samples of germanium produced by 
Welker, similar to what Bardeen and Brattain had accomplished earlier in 
December 1947. Realizing that Bell Labs' scientists had already invented the 
transistor before them, the company rushed to get its "transistron" into 
production for amplified use in France's telephone network.‎‎ 
\footnote{Footnote of the second box}‎ $\blacksquare$
‎\end{topbot}


‎«‎There are two types of transistors, which have slight differences in how 
they are used in a circuit. A bipolar transistor has terminals labeled base, 
collector, and emitter. A small current at the base terminal (that is, 
flowing between the base and the emitter) can control or switch a much 
larger current between the collector and emitter terminals. For a field- 
effect transistor, the terminals are labeled gate, source, and drain, and a 
voltage at the gate can control a current between source and drain.‎ 
\footnote{Second footnote of the main box}‎

‎\end{document}
```

Comment: The usage of the floating `figure` inside of a `tcolorbox` will result in the following error message: `Not in outer par mode[...]`. Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: Regarding the footnotes, you might want to use `\footnotemark` inside of the `tcolorbox` and `\footnotetext` right after the corresponding box.

Comment: tcolorbox uses mpfootnote (minipage counter) instead of footnote. You'd have footnote to be executed outside of the box.

Comment: @TeXnician I tried it, but did not generate footnote outside the box.

Comment: Footnotes are based on `\insert`, and there is no `\global\insert`.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314375/why-does-parbox-lose-footnotes?r=SearchResults&s=1|46.4592