# Can footnotes be printed on-demand as part of the main text?

Tags: footnotes, memoir, endnotes

**Solved with *parnotes* package.**

...

Is there a command for printing footnotes as part of the main text?  I seem to remember a way of doing that with endnotes, where the accumulated notes would show up in the text at the point where the command was placed.  However, my document makes extensive use of **both footnotes and endnotes**, so that trick won't be possible.

To clarify, this is how I envision it working...

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

In this paragraph, I wish to make footnotes.\footnote{Just like this.}
Then I wish to invoke a command to print them right there, as if they were
part of the main text, rather than at the bottom like usual.\endnote{I
also need to keep endnotes normal for a page of citations.}

\printFootnotesRightHere

The command must print the footnotes where it is called, and then clear
whatever register contained them, so that a fresh set of footnotes can be
entered.\footnote{Like this new one.}

\printFootnotesRightHere

So even on a single page, there could be several sets of footnotes,
inserted as normal text, just as if they were their own paragraphs or
lists.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. It's a bit unclear exactly what you're asking to do. Are you saying that you want two sets of endnotes (one your footnotes, and the other your endnotes)? Could you edit your question to include a compilable sample document that would show what you're doing, and explain a bit more clearly what the result should be.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want your "footnotes" to be printed between paragraphs (which would make them bodynotes).  The basic process for creating footnotes is fairly straightforward (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314375/why-does-parbox-lose-footnotes/314531?r=SearchResults&s=2|50.8785#314531).

Comment: I keep looking at the question you linked to, but I can't figure out what it's supposed to accomplish.  I don't see any sort of command used there to print the accumulated footnotes between paragraphs and then reset them.  Moreover, I've been unable to find any reference to the term "bodynotes", even though the term sounds like an accurate way to describe what I'm hoping to achieve.

Comment: Experimenting with the suggested resource, I found a way to print one footnote at a time in the body of the text, but I'm still not sure how to get several into a single list, to be placed at a chosen point in the text.

Comment: I've scoured memoir.cls, as well, and clearly this stuff is beyond me.  Forget I asked.

Comment: I must enjoy suffering, because I'm trying again.  If somebody could point me to the specific bit of code that prints the footnote data in a list, maybe I can figure out on my own how to place the list where I want it.