# Footnotes from nested multicols not displayed

Tags: luatex, footnotes, multicol

I have a document that uses `multicols` inside `multicols` for a section but when I define a footnote in the inner `multicols` environment, it is not displayed. Footnotes defined outside of `multicols` or in the outer `multicols` environment are displayed just fine.

How do I ensure all footnotes are shown?

Live demo: https://www.overleaf.com/read/dfyjqddkccrc

Full reproducible example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\title{footnote nested multicol}

\begin{document}

This is non-columned paragraph. \footnote{This footnote renders completely fine.}

\begin{multicols}{2}
foo \footnote{This footnote inside a multicols environment renders completely fine as well.}

\begin{multicols}{2}
bar \footnote{There are no signs of this footnote from multicols nested within multicols.}
\end{multicols}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I am using LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314375/why-does-parbox-lose-footnotes?r=SearchResults&s=1|47.3485

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks. The code in your answer is way over my head but it actually seems to do exactly what I want. I am just surprised there is not any less hacky way.

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\title{footnote nested multicol}
\begin{document}

This is non-columned paragraph. \footnote{This footnote renders
completely fine.}

\begin{multicols}{2}
foo \footnote{This footnote inside a multicols environment renders
completely fine as well.}
\begin{minipage}{.7\columnwidth}
\begin{multicols}{2}
bar \footnote{There are no signs of this footnote from multicols
nested within multicols.}
\end{multicols}
\end{minipage}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That does show the footnote but inside the minipage, not with the other footnotes at the document page.

Comment: And even weirder, if I move the `minipage` so that the outer `multicols` is contained within, it still shows the footnote. So it does not appear that the `multicols` is actually eating it. But who else can we blame?

Answer (score 1):

A nexted multicols generates a box like `\parbox` and parbox doesn't support footnotes or rather its footnote text is never migrated to the outside --- and that without warning, which is a flaw in LaTeX (but one that is deeply woven into the algorithm and so is unlikely to change.

What LaTeX offer though (and which is easy to use at least if you have few footnotes) is the use of `\footmark` and `\footnotetext`. Thus with

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
bar\footnotemark
\end{multicols}\footnotetext{There are signs of this footnote from multicols nested within multicols.}
```

comes out fine.