# How to add a footnote inside a pgfplotstable from a csv?

Tags: footnotes, pgfplotstable

I am writing CSV files with Python 3 and inserting the CSV in a .tex file with pgfplotstable. I want to have footnotes for some of the cells (`*`, `**`, `†`, etc.) I can easily replace them in my Python code.

**Problem:** I however can not compile the file to PDF when I do replace the footnote signs with `\footnote{the note}` in the CSV. (using [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com) and pdfLaTeX)

The table when I do not replace anything: [image]

patrimoine.csv content:

```
Patrimoine,Actifs financiers 1,Mandat 1*,Actifs financiers 2,Mandat 2*
Liquidités,0 K€,,0 K€,
Contrats euro,2 K€,0 K€,12 K€,0 K€
Gestion diversifiée,10 K€,0 K€,60 K€,30 K€
Gestion actions,120 K€,0 K€,60 K€,30 K€
Total,132 K€,0 K€,132 K€,60 K€
Rendement,7.7\%,0.0\%,6.1\%,6.5\%
Volatilité†,14.0\%,0.0\%,9.5\%**,10.3\%
```

Code for reproduction:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % décider de la taille des marges
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % couleurs
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\newcommand{\tablegray}{gray!15}

\def \insertTable#1{
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{#1}\data
        \pgfplotstabletypeset[
            string type,
            assign column name/.style={/pgfplots/table/column name={\textbf{##1}}},
            every first column/.style={postproc cell content/.append style={@cell content/.add={\bfseries}}, column type = {l}},
            every head row/.style={before row=\rowcolor{\tablegray}},
            every odd row/.style={before row=\rowcolor{\tablegray}},
            every even row/.style={before row=\rowcolor{white}},
        ]{\data}
}


\begin{document}

\insertTable{patrimoine.csv}

\end{document}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Footnotes cannot be used inside groups.  Instead you can use threeparttable or \footnotemark inside and \footnotetext outside the group.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314375/why-does-parbox-lose-footnotes

Comment: Thank you @JohnKormylo, this is a good workaround ;)