# Can the footnotetext be placed in the same body of text as the footnotemark?

Tags: footnotes

I would like to add a footnote to a text in a `multicols` environment. The content of the footnote should not be divided by the main body of text at all, neither by a rule, nor by font size.

I tried to illustrate the MWE's output and the desired output:

[image: MWE output vs. desired output]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{This is some footnote text just to clarify.}

\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Default `\footnotetext` uses `\insert\footins` to store the note.  First, it is prefomatted to start a new line.  Second, it can't be accessed within the page itself.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314375/why-does-parbox-lose-footnotes

Comment: Yes, but, honestly, why???

Comment: @MulticolMetallurgist You may have a look to `ftnright` package.

Comment: Thank you all, the ````ftnright```` package looks promising. However, I have decided to define a new command that displays a counter's value as ````\textsuperscript```` when used, increasing its value afterwards. This way, the "footnote marks" get placed. Before the "footnote texts" begin, I reset the counter to 1.